# XCode CoreData files not found/opening

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using the Xcode 3.1.4 that means SDK 3.1.2

The problem is that I cannot open .xcdatamodel (Core Data) file and I don't even get the Data Model option in Design Menu bar.

When ever I double click and try to open the file, 
**XCode gives me an error saying that it cannot find the file at (my project's path).Perhaps it was moved or deleted?** , but the file exists at the same path.

Please help me out as I haven't upgraded my system to Snow Leopard so cant use SDK 3.2

Regards
jAmi

Answer (score 0):

I think definitely one thing you can check is to ctrl-click on your file, select get info, and see if the path name is in red. If it's in red, it doesn't hurt to click choose and relink it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nopes, the path is not in red its black, do you think I am missing some sort of a plugin(for Core Data) in XCode because In the Top MenuBar>Design> I dont find Data Model option...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question, but in case anyone searches for this: I have found that **Clean** or **Clean All Targets** will fix this issue.

Aggravating, but putting `Cmd-Shift-K` on your list of remembered shortcuts is worthwhile.